# Modifying file extension in django

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a form to upload some files to my system and then work with it. First, upload the file is working well but when I want to change the extension of my uploaded file crashes.

Below I show my function,

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import os

def uploadKMZ(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Save the file updated
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        name = uploaded_file.name
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)

        # Modify the extension (NOT WORKING)
        thisFile = uploaded_file.name
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(thisFile)
        os.rename(thisFile, name + ".zip")


    return render(request, 'data_app/kmzTemplate.html')
```

The error is `FileNotFoundError`, why is not founding it if the file is the same but just changing the extension?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try modifying your extension before saving the file?
I didn't try the code below, but if feels more sensible.  Try it out.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import os

def uploadKMZ(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Save the file updated
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file.name)
        new_name = name + '.zip'
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(new_name, uploaded_file) 

    return render(request, 'data_app/kmzTemplate.html')
```